# Create new telegram chat using bot

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Can Telegram bot answer to a single user from the group if this chat (user with bot) wasn't created before? In other words I need to create a new chat with user.

Method `...sendMessage?chat_id=$userId...` works only when the user has allready chatted with the bot once.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't notice, the server retuns:
{
  "ok":false,
  "error_code":403,
  "description":"**Bot can't initiate conversation with a user**"
}

Unfortunetly nope